# Firebase Functions TypeScript unit testing devDependencies

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, firebase, dependencies, google-cloud-functions

Following the guideline here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing
I'm trying to write unit tests to my TS functions.
here's my package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
    "test": "mocha --reporter spec"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/algoliasearch": "^3.27.0",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^4.6.0",
    "@types/stripe": "^5.0.11",
    "algoliasearch": "^3.27.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.12.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.3",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.4",
    "stripe": "^5.8.0",
    "webpack": "^4.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^9.6.6",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.2",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "ts-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "typescript": "^2.8.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.2",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

and I have 1 problem and 1 question.

**problem:**
I can't import the firebase-functions-test
in my index.test.ts file.
it is looking for it in dependencies only and not in devDependencies...
(adding it inside dependencies solve it).

**question:**
Can I move all the @types to devDependencies?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I am right you probably get error something like

> Module 'firebase-functions-test' is not listed as dependency in package.json

In fact this is because you have enabled tslint rule no-implicit-dependencies. You can disable it and then you will not get error when importing devDependencies in your unit test.

Answer (score 1):

You can change set tslint to consider dev,

```
{
...
"rules": {
    "no-implicit-dependencies": [true, "dev"],
    ...
}
```

see https://github.com/houndci/hound/issues/1522#issuecomment-415760094